# Render farm with different versions of Blender

Tags: rendering

I have a lot of old laptops and would like to use them to render. However they don't have powerful enough GPUs to run Blender 2.8. Can I render something made in 2.8 on older Blender versions which do run on these machines? Would I need to bake everything first? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To some extent, but it's not recommended. If you use Legacy Mesh Format you can open it in versions prior to 2.63.